# JavaScript NaN when adding two values

Tags: javascript, nan, multiplication

OK, this is driving me insane. I have JavaScript code like this:

```
var totalvalue;

var price = xmlhttp.responseText.split(':')[1].replace("}", "");

totalvalue = price * assetsArray[i + 1];

console.log(totalvalue);
```

Now this piece of code works just fine. It's in a for loop and it's correctly displaying the right numbers (5000 and 2000) in the console log. However, when I try to add both numbers together and show them in the log like this:

```
totalvalue += price * assetsArray[i + 1];
```

the value of totalvalue becomes NaN. I know that the multiplication equals a meaningful number so why doesn't it do the same when i try to add them together?

Comment: `totalvalue` is uninitialized initially, so it's undefined. The first iteration results in `totalvalue = (price * assetsArray[i + 1]) + undefined` which is NaN. Give `totalvalue` an initial value (of say, 0)